# Accessing the google hangouts "talk-gadget" iFrame on google+, the extension, etc

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-hangouts

I am wondering if it is possible with a chrome extension to access the google+ hangouts text chat/group chat iFrame elements, and modify their DOM.

I know there are CORS restrictions, as it's an iFrame, but is there any possible way?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a way could help you out. When loaded in a Hangout, the contents of the Content element will be loaded inside of an iframe inside the Hangout. By including the hangout.js file, your application will have access to the Hangouts JavaScript API. See the reference on link: https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/writing